# Передача значений в функцию по ссылке python

Tags: python, python-3.x, область-видимости

Есть несколько глобальных переменных. В функции main() одна из них передается в другую функцию. Как во второй функции изменить глобальную переменную? Пример кода:

```
global S = False
global B = False
global M = True

def main():
  if S == True:
    print("Это не выведется")

  setP(S)
  if S == True:
    print("Это выведется")

def setP(param):
  ...........
  ...........
```

Comment: У вас код синтаксически неправильный

Comment: Это пример кода

Answer (score 3):

Добавляю пример изменения значения глобальной переменной:

```
S = False


def setS(value):
    # Если global не писать, тогда будет создана новая переменная в этой
    # области видимости (внутри функции)
    global S
    S = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if S:
        print("Это не выведется")

    setS(True)

    if S:
        print("Это выведется")
```

Консоль:

```
Это выведется
```